# How to make either of two fields required in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, required-field

I'm new to MS Access, and I have a form with the fields [name] and [company]. I want to make it required for the user to fill out either of those, but not necessarily both. They can fill out [name], [company] or both, but they can't leave both of them blank.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in vba:

Create an  Eventhandler that runs before the saving of a dataset and tell it to cancel the update if your conditions are not met:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If (isnull(me!name) and isnull(me.company) then
        msgBox "Give me more !"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Or simply: `If IsNull(Me!Name + Me!Company) Then`

Comment: This works, but creates a problem: If I start entering data for a new record and then delete it, Access wont let me move to previous records because neither of the two fields contain anything.

Comment: Me.Undo cancels everything you did on the current record and lets you out of a new  record. Either put it after Cancel=true or (better): make a new button for it.

Comment: @Gustav I don't think you can add (Null + String). I have tried `If IsNull([Name] + [Company])` in Data Macro, and returns TRUE when either both are Nulls or one of them is Null

Comment: Yes, exactly. Certainly intended - to avoid having two `IsNull`. A matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: @Gustav Then it is not the same because `IsNull([Name]) And IsNull(Company])` returns true **only** if both fields are Null. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, you are right. I didn't reread(!) the question. It should be: `If IsNull(Me!Name & Me!Company) Then`. Not sure, though, if that is any improvement to the answer (which I did upvote). Thanks for the head-up!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend **Data Macros** in this case (if you're using Access 2010 or later). The advantage over **VBA** is that Data Macro runs at the engine level, so if you have multiple forms with these fields you don't have to duplicate your VBA to every one of them. This also eliminates the problem with starting entering data and then deleting them.

Go to Table design, click **Create Data Macros** > **Before Change** and add **If** condition like this:

[image: Data macro Before Update]

You can use VBA to catch the error number 1 to do some stuff. As Access say, the error numbers are user defined and has no meaning to Access.

Comment: @Jeppe I also think You shouldn't name your field `Name` as it makes some trouble when using VBA. I cannot remember what exactly though